# Player for streaming audio/video on Drupal 7

Tags: video, audio, media-player, streaming, drupal

I want to stream audio and video files on my Drupal 7 site.

The module(s) must be available from drupal.org (but installing external third-party libraries is fine, in case they are gratis and free/libre/open), should be stable, should not be abandoned.

#### Technologies

- I can use a HTML5 theme (in case HTML5’s `audio`/`video` will be used).
- Flash may be used as fallback, but it should not be the default player.
- Requiring JavaScript is fine, but a non-JS fallback would of course be great.

#### Formats

- It should be compatible with as many common browsers/devices as possible.
- The author will only upload a single format, so if other formats are needed for compatibility, the conversion should happen automatically on the server.
- I don’t know exactly which formats the author will upload, but nothing special I guess: MP3, AVI, MP4, …

#### Quality

- Great if the module allows resizing / changing the quality, but that’s not required.

#### Drupal integration

- It would be nice to have a single module (or even field) that can handle both (audio and video), but that’s not required.
- It would ideally use the core File field and provide a display formatter for the player, but that’s not required. I’m starting a new site, so I’m still flexible.

#### Player features

- Nothing special required, just play/pause and a timeline.
- It should not start automatically.
- Keyboard accessibility would be a big plus.
- A setting that enables repeat would be nice.

Comment: I guess it should be able to resize videos? Uploaded videos are often really big, and need to be resized before being served, especially for mobile devices.

Comment: Can't you just use the browsers built in HTML5 player? Use the `<video>` tags, or `<audio>`, just like you can use `<img>`? Doesn't start automatically (but can be set to), can be set to repeat, most have keyboard integration... anything after IE9 will support it (IE9 included)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Thanks, updated the question. It would be useful, but I don’t want to require it (I think most of the author’s media files are already in a web-suitable quality and small).

Comment: @CalvT: I think this would be fine, but AFAIK different browsers/OS support different formats, so the solution would have to convert them. And I’d like to prevent having to change the field template to add `video`/`audio` markup myself, so the module should do this automatically.

Comment: MP4 is supported by basically every browser since the HTML5 video tag came out. I can see your point though - and wish you good luck in finding it! This sort of this is why I left Drupal for Wordpress - it's already built in in WordPress